# Vertical align in tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

I'm having an object in a table and I'm unable to set vertical align (it doesn't seem to work).

Why is that?

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/PHDWz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I give the td a height.. the content is vertical aligned in the middle....

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="width: 180px">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Textarea</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td height="400">Bla bla bla! Write something if you like! </td>
            <td>
                <textarea></textarea>  <span><img src="http://www.qualtrics.com/university/wp-content/plugins/wp-print/images/printer_famfamfam.gif" alt="printer"> A printer!</span>
            </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No it's totally not :) Try adding height to textarea and you will see why.

Comment: I don't know what you mean.. it's still in the middle. Do you mean that the "a printer" text is not centered? then you should wrap the textarea and the text in a div... then that whole div is being aligned

Answer (score 1):

just add an additional column to avoid the "A printer!" link being forced to be kind of attached as align-bottom to the textarea. 
In your css you may omit the vertical-align for the span as you have this duplicated in the outer td.

```
<table cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" style="width: 180px">Description</th>
        <th scope="col" colspan="2">Textarea</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Bla bla bla! Write something if you like! </td>
        <td><textarea></textarea></td>
        <td><span><img src="http://www.qualtrics.com/university/wp-content/plugins/wp-print/images/printer_famfamfam.gif" alt="printer"> A printer!</span>
        </td>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text in the left column sits in the middle vertically when I extend the textbox. This is using  Safari, please elaborate if something else